# System.Transaction in VisualStudio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, asp.net-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010/.net 4.
I want to do something inside 'TransactionScope' BUT I dont have System.Transaction support!!
Does anyone know whats wrong here??

Comment: What does `I dont have System.Transaction support` mean?

Comment: well, when I try to add 'using system.transaction', it doesn't allow me. no intellisence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the System.Transactions reference to your project?

(Right click the References folder -> Add Reference)

Comment: thanks. My lack of knowledge. I didn't know that I have to add it separately.